# How do I get an ubuntu server/minimal installation with zsys and zfs?

Tags: server, software-installation, zfs

My old server died due to some hardware issues and I'm in the situation where I get to stand up a new server the "right" way.

I'd like to get a fully CLI install up, but I'd like to get ZFS on root like I would on 20.04, and get zsys features like snapshots on updates and a few other useful bits I've gotten used to on desktop ubuntu ZFS.

Is there any supported way that would let me do this? I'm installing over KVM over IP so while I'd prefer pure CLI/TUI installers, I'd be good with using the standard ubuntu installer if it would let me end up with a server or minimal system.

I'm not *too* picky over versions but I'd like something out of the box, without needing to use tricks like doing a normal install then pivotroot.

The [openzfs setup documentation](https://openzfs.github.io/openzfs-docs/Getting%20Started/Ubuntu/Ubuntu%2020.04%20Root%20on%20ZFS.html#ubuntu-installer) might be an option, but leaves out talking about zsys, and if any configuration is needed. I also can't really get the desktop spin booted over the KVM over IP setup that the provider uses.